# jQuery set min and max value for phone number with validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I need to validate my `input type="text"` when keypress with minimum value 7 and maximum value 13. And also I need to validate to enter numbers only. I have tried with some reference stack but failed to resolve. Anyone help me achieve this.

```js
$("#phone").bind("keyup keydown", function() {  
    var amount = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if (amount) {
        if (amount > 7 || amount < 13) {
            $("span.phonealert").html("Your number must be between 7 and 13");
        } else
  if(amount < 13) {
            $("span.phonealert").html("valid phone number");
        }
    } else {
        $("span.phonealert").html("Enter numbers only");
    }
});
```

```css
#phone {
  height:40px;
  width:200px;
  padding:5px;
  font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" maxlength="13" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="eg: 01234567890" value=""/>
<span class="phonealert"></span>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to validate phone number, that is minimum 7 digit long and maximum 13 digits long.

Comment: @iNullPointer Yes.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: @iNullPointer can send sample link as per my question with alert msg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You Should Use Regular Expression For Validating It

#### Function For Validating Numbers

```
function verifyPhoneNumber(number){
  var validity = new RegExp("^[0-9]{7,13}$");
  return validity.test(number);
}
```

#### Function For Checking and Validating Key Press

```
$('#phone').keypress(function(e){
  // 48-57 are code of digits 0-9.
  if (![48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57].includes(e.keyCode)){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Enter digits only.");
  }
});
```

This function will return true if the number is valid (i.e., it contains only digits `0 to 9` and minimum `7 digits` and maximum `13 digits` long) otherwise false.

Comment: Can you add sample link with example alert message

Comment: @Sharvan [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iNullPointer/9ftvo68d/#&togetherjs=hxthsw0sF2)

Comment: @Sharvan hope this will help you.

Comment: When start type if I enter character need to alert enter numbers only.

Comment: @Sharvan I've updated my answer. Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: @Sharvan Feeling glad to help you.